# How to add URL Parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to add an Url Parameter.

---

For example: http://localhost:65319/Example.aspx?FirstName=value

---

This is my current code

---

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using con As New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=WJNJPHR8TCX8P\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Fabrics;Integrated Security=True;"),
          cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM [Client] WHERE OR [FirstName] = ?", con)
               con.Open()

           cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = FNameTextBox.Text

           dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
           End Using

           GridView1.DataSourceID = Nothing
           GridView1.DataSource = dt
           GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me

Comment: I have to agree with @WoutervanVegchel.  Your question makes no sense.  Are you saying that you want to add another condition to the `WHERE` clause based on a `URL` column?

Comment: Sorry for that. What I mean  is how to add an url parameter. For example. http://localhost:65319/Example.aspx?FirstName=value.

Comment: in this line : cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM [Client] WHERE OR [FirstName] = ?", con), replace '?' with '@FirstName'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consult [MSDN- How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Forms Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

You could look at the query string section and do something like this:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = Request.QueryString("FirstName")
```

Or even better, add some validation to ensure that the FirstName is populated:

```
If Not Request.QueryString("FirstName") Is Nothing Then
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = Request.QueryString("FirstName")
Else
      ????
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. @Haydn Dias

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Comment: No. But thank you for your help and suggestion @Haydn Dias